# Inserting values into a table via a stored procedure

Tags: database, stored-procedures, db2

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that inserts some data into a table when the first table get update.

Explanation:

I have two identical tables, `Table1` and `Table2`. I would like that when the `table 1` gets a row update the information for that row gets inserted in `Table2` as well.

I was thinking in a stored procedure, but I'm not sure how will be.

Thanks a lot.

By the way I'm using IBM DB2 for iSeries.

Comment: IMHO you better use a trigger for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a trigger like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MYTRIGGER
 AFTER INSERT ON TABLE1
 REFERENCING NEW ROW AS N
 FOR EACH ROW
 INSERT INTO TABLE2 (COL1, COL2)
  VALUES (N.COL1, N.COL2 )
```

For more information please see the [Infocenter on CREATE TRIGGER](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000931.html&resultof=%2522%2563%2572%2565%2561%2574%2565%2522%2520%2522%2563%2572%2565%2561%2574%2522%2520%2522%2574%2572%2569%2567%2567%2565%2572%2522%2520). You must cover also UPDATE and DELETE depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

In LUW you can use Temporal capabilities, by adding the necessary column and activating system-period data. In this case, you do not need triggers, because DB2 does everything for you.

However, you are using iSeries, and that platform does not have the latest features of db2 for z/OS and db2 for LUW.

(I know that this is not the answer of that question, but I wanted to share it)